# I need to make group records of users activites in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need hourly numbers of users who have entered in the last 24 hours. I have to group it in 1 hour intervals from 00:00 to 23:59. However, users must have unique records.

**How can I make a sql query of it or eloquent query?**

My Solution is:

```
SELECT count(user_id) as Users,
CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ':59:59' ) 
) as Time_Frame
FROM table_name
where created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY 
DATE(created_at), 
HOUR(created_at)
order by count(user_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the most recent complete calendar date, you can use

```
select maketime(hour(enteredAt), 0, 0) as hour, count(*)
from t
where enteredAt >= curdate() - interval 1 day and
      enteredAt < curdate()
group by hour
order by hour;
```